# Parse JS SDK: Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided

Tags: javascript, angular, parse-platform

I need to use masterKey inside my angular2 app, but I can't pass it to `initialize` function and I can't google out why.
From `package.json`: `"parse": "~1.9.2"`.

Initialization:

```
import {Parse} from '~/node_modules/parse/dist/parse';

@Injectable()
export class TFCloudService {
    constructor() {
        this.parse = Parse;

        Parse.initialize(appConfig.parse.appId, null, appConfig.parse.masterKey);
        Parse.serverURL = appConfig.parse.clientServerUrl;
        Parse.liveQueryServerURL = appConfig.parse.liveQueryServerURL;
    }
}
```

Error source:

```
this.edittedUser.save(null, {useMasterKey: true})
.then((user) => {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Error text:
`Error: Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided.`

`appConfig.parse.masterKey` works fine, I checked that line with hard-coded key too, but got the same result.

Comment: You shouldn't use your master key within an angular application as you make it available to everyone. Any operation requiring the use of the master key should be done server side.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually guessed the right way to pass that key:

```
Parse.initialize(appConfig.parse.appId);
Parse.masterKey = appConfig.parse.masterKey;
```

Comment: Saved my life, thank you. Two days of searching. This actually works **with browser SDK**. The **nodejs** version requires the normal initialization.

Comment: I used this method it is working fine but when I try to save Parse.File I am getting error 'TypeError: Cannot create a Parse.File with that data'

Comment: I want to stress out that using your masterKey in a client app IS A MAJOR SECURITY FLAW, you're basically letting your admin username /password pair to all your user data, database etc... @kembse

Answer (score 0):

[By the book](https://dashboard.back4app.com/apidocs?javascript#installing-parse-sdk), you never should use the Master Key in the frontend.

So, the right way should be to create [cloud functions](https://www.back4app.com/docs/get-started/cloud-functions) for operations that require master key

```
const Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com'; // This is your Server URL
// Remember to inform BOTH the Back4App Application ID AND the JavaScript KEY
Parse.initialize(
  'APP_ID', // This is your Application ID
  'JS_KEY', // This is your Javascript key
  'MASTER_KEY' // This is your Master key (never use it in the frontend)
);

Parse.Cloud.define("hello", async (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query("SomeClass");
    const results = await query.distinct("field"); // needs Master Key
    // ...
});
```

Then, call it on browser apps

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize(
        "APP_ID",
        "JS_KEY"
    );
    Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/'
    const helloFunction = await Parse.Cloud.run("hello");
</script>
```