# Parse: How can you have full administrative privileges in code?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I am making a cron job that writes to my Parse database, but all the documents in my database can only be read/write by the user that created it (ACL). Is there a way to overrule ACL so that cron job can basically have all the priveledges I have on my Parse dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you can use the master key. And use { useMasterKey: true } for the calls that require administrative privileges

Comment: The plug! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40223311/parse-js-sdk-cannot-use-the-master-key-it-has-not-been-provided) was also helpful.